# Azure AD Application not appearing in existing AD App list for an Azure web application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I was just going through some walkthrough where I created an Azure AD App to use it as an authorization/authentication in my Azure web application.

**Now when I go to select existing AD app for my Azure website (App Services) it doesn't appear in my Azure AD Applications list.**

The path to add existing AD app is "App Services > MyAzureApp > Authentication/Authorization > Auzre Active Directory > Express > Select existing AD App"

I have used following settings for my Azure AD app:

**Sign-on URL:**
https://login.windows.net

**Reply URLs:**
https://msmanaged-na.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect

**Required permissions:**
Azure Service Management API > Access Azure Service Management as organization users

**Keys:**
Added a key and set it's expiration date to 1 year

Help please.

**Update (@dstrockis):**
I pasted this in the browser 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/(tenantname).onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=(API Acces-Keys-GeneratedKey)=&redirect_uri=(https://azuresitename.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback)&response_mode=query&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid&nonce=12345

And I got a bad request. See image below

[image]

Comment: have you ever got this resolved? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Yes, usign the manual approach mentioned in the Flemin's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to configure authentication for your application, please follow the Manual approach mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/). I have done this to my App service and its working fine.

Comment: I tried the manual approach. Now when I browse the web application it returns an error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". Any idea about this?

Comment: Its difficult to judge from just this error. Please make sure you have tried incognito mode, "https" in reply URL, check if the Subscription is correctly linked to the Active Directory, re-check all configurations

Comment: That was a configuration error on my side. Apologies for belated feedback.

Answer (score 2):

In the Azure Active Directory admin center, when I browse to Azure Active Directory > App registrations, the app I registered does not show up. When I change the view settings from "My apps" (selected by default) to "All Apps" it then shows in the list. No need to change owners, at least for my purposes

The owner setting was a clue--

Switching from "My Apps" view to "All apps" allowed my my app to show up.

Comment: Clarify and elaborate.

Comment: In the Azure Active Directory admin center, when I browse to Azure Active Directory > App registrations, the app I registered does not show up.  When I change the view settings from "My apps" (selected by default) to "All Apps" it then shows in the list.  No need to change owners, at least for my purposes

Answer (score 1):

In Azure AD there is a difference between "registering" an app and "provisioning" it into your tenant.  The Azure AD portal UX is currently only doing the former, but not the latter.  The team is aware of the problem and working on a fix.

In the meantime the best workaround is to simulate a sign-in to the app, which will "provision" the app into your Azure AD tenant.

If you complete the below request and paste it into a browser, and sign-in with an account in your tenant, you should see it show up.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{common-or-tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client-id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_mode=query&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid&nonce=12345`

Comment: I tried the above mentioned request by replacing {tenant} with <mytrialorg>.onmicrosoft.com, client_id with Azure AD app's key that we generate in API Access > Keys section, redirect_uri with 'https://<azurewebsitename>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback' but I recieved a bad request error upon sign-in.

Comment: Use the application ID, not the app key

Comment: but i received back response with code, id token and session state.

Comment: Ok then it's probably an issue unrelated to Azure AD, but rather app services integration with AAD. Sounds like the guys below are more knowledgeable about that. Sorry for the red herring

Answer (score 1):

Late to the cake but believe it will help.

When you create your app registration don't forget to assign an owner to it (Settings -> Owner) before you close registration pane.

Otherwise it's created but won't display on the list as seems like it doesn't have a default owner.

[image: Example of creating an App Registration]

Comment: Owner is not filled when your an "Global Administrator"

Answer (score 1):

Well for me,

just updating the App Registration manifest file

```
"publicClient": false
```

to

```
"publicClient": null
```

does the trick

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

From your error message in your image, it seems that the application was not added in your Azure AD tenant.

> Now when I go to select existing AD app for my Azure website (App Services) it doesn't appear in my Azure AD Applications list.

When select existing AD app in Azure portal, please make sure your app was added in ‘current Active Directory’ (Highlight in below screenshot). It is very easy if you create a new AD app in Azure portal.
[image]

If you confuse with the parameters in Azure AD work flow, Please have a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/).

Comment: I confirmed the AD app is added to the current active directory. It's an Azure trial org having only a default AD.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your application is not registered as an Enterprise Application, which is what I found my application needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Azure Function not showing up in my KeyVault Access. Giving me a cryptic error ([error] aadsts900023" specified tenant identifier is neither a valid dns name, nor a valid external domain.)

Ended up, that the access to key vault disappeared, but I couldn't find the app to give it permissions again.

To resolve this I went to the Azure Function > Function Settings > Platform Features section.

Under the General Settings, selected "All Settings".

On this page select "Identity" under the "Settings" section.

In the "System assigned" tab, Turn on "Status".

Which will then give:
"This resource is registered with Azure Active Directory. You can control its access to services like Azure Resource Manager, Azure Key Vault, etc."