# Azure AD B2C issues referencing another AD App: Select API drop down is always empty

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using this sample as a starting point: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/

But instead of calling an existing API I'm trying to call graph.

The actual issue I'm running into is that when I go to reference any API/APP in my B2C app there are no options under 'Select API'

[image]

What I am trying to reference is a AD App I created that has access to Graph.

I tried a number of the suggestions listed here: [Azure AD Application not appearing in existing AD App list for an Azure web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835124/azure-ad-application-not-appearing-in-existing-ad-app-list-for-an-azure-web-appl)

Including adding myself as the owner of the AD App, but I can't make it appear in AD B2C.

I've also tried signin in and out and I've tried a couple different browsers just in case.

My B2C tenant isn't linked to a subscription so that could be the issue but I'm not sure why since both my AD B2C and my AD App live in the same tenant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access can only be granted from one Azure AD B2C-registered application, i.e. the client application, to another Azure AD B2C-registered application, i.e. the resource application.

The Graph API is *not* an Azure AD B2C-registered application.

Alternatively, you'll either have to implement [a backend for the frontend](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/), where it's the backend application that integrates with the Graph API or implement a custom policy that interacts with it.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've upvoted this feature on uservoice now. Seems like this should be easier to do then it currently is!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call you need to register an application in azure ad tenant. And azure b2c cannot find the application which has graph api permissions. Because it is not in your b2c tenant. Regarding how to call graph api, please refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet